# Passing data from blade to blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel, parameters

I have a page where you can create your workout plan. Second page contains "pre-saved" workouts and I want them to load by passing parameters from second page to first. If you directly access first page, you create your workout plan from scratch.

// first page = https://prnt.sc/y4q77z

// second page = https://prnt.sc/y4qfem ; where you can check which one you want to pass to first page

// final step looks like this: https://prnt.sc/y4qh2q - but my URL looks like this:

> [www.example.com/training/plan?sabloni%5B%5D=84&sabloni%5B%5D=85&sabloni%5B%5D=86](http://www.example.com/training/plan?sabloni%5B%5D=84&sabloni%5B%5D=85&sabloni%5B%5D=86)

> this 84,85,86 are IDS

Can I pass params without changing URL ? Like having only /training/plan without anything after ?

```
public function plan(Request $request){
  $workout = false;
  if($request->workout){
    $workout = $request->workout;
    $workout = SablonTrening::find($sabloni); // $workout = array [1,3,4,5,6]
  }
  return view('trener.dodaj_trening', compact('workout'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting to the `/training/plan` page with `GET` request, you could simply change it to `POST`. That way the parameters would be hidden in the `URL` but would be present in the `request body`. You would need a new post route:

```
Route::post('/training/plan', 'YourController@plan')->name('training.plan');
```

And then, in the form where you are selecting these plans, change the method on submit:

```
<form action="{{route('training.plan')}}">
   //Your inputs
</form>
```

Your method should still work if your inputs stay the same.

Note: Not sure you would still keep the functionalities that you need, since I can't see all the logic you have.

If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: Well setting POST method I think won't help, because accessing POST page without sending any request isn't possible which in my case it's a problem.

Comment: How do you send these parameters `sabloni%5B%5D=84&sabloni%5B%5D=85&sabloni%5B%5D=86` ? There must be some inputs that are doing this, since you're getting them to your controller method

Comment: I have checkboxes with values. It's simple GET method, I tried with ajax too but it's the same result. Sending this params to the controller are optional. If there is not params, page should load something different.

Comment: Then the only two ways I could think of are POST method or somehow save these parameters in session via ajax, and then load them when you need them

Comment: I am currently doing in cookie. When I tried with post, I couldn't access /training/plan directly, only if parameters are sent.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from on blade to another blade.

- At the end of first post before `redirect()-route('myroute')` add `$request->session()->put('data', $mydata);`
- At the begining of the route `'myroute'`, just get back your data with `$data = $request->old('data');`